# Excel does not calculate cell

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have made a loop, that need to run, whenever a #N/A value is showing.
Afterwards it needs to calculate the cell, copy and paste it as a value, as it is a big database.
The loop works, but the calculation does not. Did i do something wrong?

```
Dim i As Integer, LastCell As Range

'Find last row
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    For i = 4 To LastRow
    If Application.IsNA(Cells(i, 14)) Then
        Cells(i, 14).Formula = Cells(4, 14).Formula
        Cells(i, 14).Calculate
        Cells(i, 14).Copy
        Cells(i, 14).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
    Next i
```

Comment: What's the formula in cell `N4`? Do you really need to include the 4th row in the loop? If you want to replace the `#N/A` values with the value in cell `N4` you might as well just use `Cells(i, "N").Value = Cells(4, "N").Value` in the *If* clause. If not, let us know what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It might help not to start i on 4 to get the formula if you're going to copy paste it as values in the first iteration so there's no longer any formula to be copied  (unless you know for a fact N4 won't be #N/A) :)

Comment: Before running the code, does the relevant range `N5:NLastRow` contain values or are there formulas that you need to keep after the code has run?

Comment: You're talking about a "big database", does your database have more than 32,767 rows? I'm asking because you're using an Integer for the row-iteration.

Comment: @VBasic2008 =RIGHT(VLOOKUP(CoaterBatch[@Batch];'FG results'!A:G;2;FALSE);3), i don't need to include row 4, as it is containing the formula already

Comment: @VBasic2008 It does not contain any important information, as the information will be overwritten in #N/A cells with the right information.

Comment: @Notus_Panda No it does not, approx 6000 rows ;)

Comment: It won't calculate the cell, but will run the command of copying the formula and copy and paste it as the value of N4. But it needs to do a calculation, before pasting the data as values. Or else i could just copy the N4 and down, which is not what i want. In other terms, N6000 it gets the same value as N4, which is not right.

Comment: Stop feeding us crumbs of information at a time and add all of it to your question. There is still vital information missing. What is the name of the worksheet containing the `CoaterBatch` table? It looks like you don't need a formula in the first row of the table. Is the data in columns `A:B` (no need to use `A:G` if you're returning the 2nd column) of worksheet `FG Results` also in a table? If so, what is the table name and what are the titles of the 1st and 2nd headers? If not, what is the first worksheet row (header row + 1) of the data? What should be returned if there is no match?

Comment: Is your calculation set to manual because `.Calculate` shouldn't be necessary. Which formula is in N4? Also, when you step through the code with F8, can you check if the formula isn't botched, i.e. N4 = M4+L4 but when you set the formula to be the same as N4, it'll also be the exact same like N10 = M4 + L4. To fix this, use `.FormulaR1C1` instead of `.Formula`

Answer (score 1):

### Conditionally Update Column With Formulas Then Values

[image]

- For the formulas to update correctly, the cell, containing the formula to be copied, needs to be a cell of the range.

```vb
Sub UpdateColumn()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    
    ' Reference the single-column range.
    
    Dim rg As Range
    With ws.Range("N4")
        Set rg = Intersect(.Resize(ws.Rows.Count - .Row + 1), ws.UsedRange)
    End With
    
    If rg Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No data found.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Combine the first cell and any other '#N/A' cells into a range.
    
    Dim urg As Range, cell As Range, IsNotFirst As Long
    
    For Each cell In rg.Cells
        If IsNotFirst Then ' add any other '#N/A' cell
            If Application.IsNA(cell.Value) Then
                Set urg = Union(urg, cell)
            End If
        Else ' add first
            Set urg = cell
            IsNotFirst = True
        End If
    Next cell
    
    ' Check if no updates are necessary.
    If urg.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        MsgBox "The column had already been updated!", vbExclamation
        Exit Sub
    End If
    
    ' Update the column.
    
    ' Write the formula to the combined range in one go.
    urg.Formula = urg.Cells(1).Formula
    ' Convert the single-column range to values (excluding the 1st cell)
    ' in one go. This is much faster than looping over the cells or areas
    ' but it assumes there are no other formulas to keep.
    With rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    
    ' Inform.
    
    MsgBox "Column updated.", vbInformation
 
End Sub
```

Comment: For a filtered range, i.e. `urg`, you can also loop to give it the ol' `.Value = .Value` which is surprisingly fast still (I use it when getting rid of formulas so they don't update when getting rid of a filter), *IF* OP would want to keep other formulas. However, we don't even know what exactly prevented his formulas from working..